# Cannot install pip with pypy: "Fatal RPython error: UnicodeDecodeError"

Tags: python, pip, pypy

I'm using Windows 10 (64bit, zh-cn) with pypy (2.4 32bit based on python 3.2.5).

When trying to install **pip** from **pypy**,

```
  > pypy get-pip.py
```

after a short delay, the **pypy.exe** would stop response and then the following logging shows in the command prompt:

```
  Fatal RPython error: UnicodeDecodeError
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

there is bug in the version.... try to change the display language, Location and Format in "Region and language" to English... this might solve your issue

Comment: Thanks, but do I need to do this everytime I want to use **pypy**?

Comment: once you do that i dont think so you need to change it every time.

Comment: Well, I tried, now there's a new error: **"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'**.

Comment: there's a problem updating your pip version due to language....try to install it using easy_install try this link for setuptools...https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools  ....  If fixed mark the answer as solved.....Upgrade it on windows using following command....       pypy -m pip install -U pip

Comment: Do you mean install **pip** through **easy_install**? And after I turned my locale back to zh-cn, when trying to **import pip** in **pypy**, there's still that **UnicodeDecodeError**. So I'll probably give up **pypy** for now, hopefully it could be fixed soon.

Comment: yep you need to keep the language English only instead Use PyCharm or Python for visual studios they work very well.. so mark the answer as accepted to close this question